# which kind of software we can develop with assembly languge

Tags: architecture, assembly

I am Student of Computer Sciences and learning assembly language. Now i want to make a project in assembly language kindly tell me that what kind of application are making with assembly language. So i select the appropiate project for my subject.

Comment: If you're in school, have you tried asking your professor/instructor for suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Assembly, being the low-level programming language that it is, can be used to develop anything, from a small "hello, world!" program up to an operating system. Once upon a time (back in the 40s) that was all developers had to work with, but then high-level languages started coming out and people quickly moved forward.

Today, the use of Assembly language is mainly contained to devices without adequate compilers and for hand-crafted well-optimized code. That said, with today's architecture it is quite hard to produce a piece of assembly code that's more optimized than what a modern compiler would give you.

For your purposes, it depends on the project scope and requirements. Bear in mind that even a very simple project, like an interactive console-based tic-tac-toe can be quite large in assembly. Here are some examples for a small project:

1. **Guess the number**: the PC will pick a random number [1..100] and the user will need to guess it.
2. **Find the divisors**: given a number from the user, find all the divisors of this number.
3. **Permutate a string**: given a string from the user, find all the permutations of this string.

Comment: The first assembly languages were not until the 1950s - back in the 1940s there was just machine code.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you can build any software using Assemble language; however, it is appropriate to use Assemble language only in following situations:

(1) To communicate with hardware directly. For example, writing hardware Drivers.

(2) To use low-level OS service (or hack the OS). For example, writing virus or anti-virus software.

(3) Write highly efficient program. Assemble code generates very small executable.It is perfect choice if the memory of the device which is intended to run the program is very limited. Also, in theory, and most of the times, Assemble program runs faster than the programs created using high-level languages.

A real example from my experience is that I used assemble language to intercept Windows APIs to introduce some Arabic language services to English Windows 98 long time ago. Also, I had to use Assemble language to create a Arabic String utility which was very frequently utilized by the core and it was proved that using Assemble language was a right choice for that matter.

Comment: -1 this is wrong. I (and many others) have developed many Windows GUI applications in assembly. The source code is extremely clear although not using HLA (and a lot more understandable than many equivalent C/C++/java and other apps) It didn't take more time developing in assembly than it would have taken me doing it in a higher level language.

Comment: Yes. There are many applications written in Assemble. But it is impractical to use Assembly for Desktop GUI applications. I bet I (and many others) can create a GUI application using VB/C# faster than using Assembly. If you found using Assemble to create an GUI app takes same amount of time as you use high level language, it is definitely right time for you to start looking at high-level languages more in detail. Also don't forget to clarify who are the "many others".

Comment: There are resource compilers for assembly (winasm also let you place components like in VB) and I can make a complex GUI in a few minutes. I can use the windows API for the rest. How is that different. I suggest you take a look at the tools available.

Comment: Complex UI in a few minutes? How complex is it? And Windows API? The old sendMessage(hInstance,msg,wParam,lParam) and pushing all parameters into the stack before a function call? How is it easier than  obj.prop1=val in VB? Dear friend, you may like Assembly very much; but, it doesn't mean it fits for the majority of development cases.Also, I have never said one can't develop GUI app using Assembly. You can create any application even using machine code directly, but it doesn't justify its usage. Use a technology when it makes sense bro.

Comment: It can be as complex as you want. It's just a matter of drawing controls on the screen bro. It's not because you don't know the technology that it is bad. The op asks what software can be developped in asm, not which language is best for the job. You answering that it can only be used for drivers and low level stuff just shows your ignorance about the subject, friend.

Comment: Please read my answer carefully before putting any comment. I have never said Assembly can only be used to create low-level stuff. Reading carefully before giving comment is always good thing. And, my answer got two votes no matter how you disliked it.

Comment: "it is APPROPRIATE to use Assemble language ONLY in following situations": This is simply wrong. It's not because the linux kernel is written in C that it is appropriate to use C only when writing kernels, that's stupid. And the upvotes you got just shows that there are 2 more people on SO who know nothing about assembly but are not ashamed to vote. End of conversation, thank you.

Comment: With regard to 3), it's true that well-tuned assembly code can outperform compiled code, but this is only true for _well-tuned_ asm. If you don't know what you're doing and how the CPU microarchitecture works asm code can easily be worse.